# Correct Xpath query for Google Sheets XImport function problem

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xml-import

I am trying to pull the "low price" from this web page url `https://www.nbatopshot.com/listings/p2p/208ae30a-a4fe-42d4-9e51-e6fd1ad2a7a9+2d0fe5aa-617a-4492-89d2-faa125e4b196` using Google Sheets XImport.

I copied the xPath from the developer console which returns this:

```
//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span
```

However my formula when putting those two together does now work and returns "imported content is empty message).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.nbatopshot.com/listings/p2p/208ae30a-a4fe-42d4-9e51-e6fd1ad2a7a9+2d0fe5aa-617a-4492-89d2-faa125e4b196","html/head/title"),"USD .([\d,]+)"))`

As for the IMPORTXML itself, the extraction isn't from the body of the HTML. At a glance, what you see in the body seems to be generated by script, which you would not be able to retrieve. But it also looks like PHP is generating the static header title *from* that same data in this case, so I was able to retrieve it from there. (I found this in Chrome by right-clicking on the page and doing a 'Find' for "Lebron.")

`REGEXEXTRACT` pulls just the low figure, and `VALUE` converts it to a usable number.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! If I wanted to grab for example, the player name, and the series subheadings underneath his name, would I just use H1 etc.

Comment: As I mentioned, the on-page data you see is generated by script, so you can't extract any of that. It just so happens that the webmaster created the meta title from pieces of data also found in the script-generated page and used that as a hard-coded title (not the norm for most websites). The data included in that title is a single string exactly as follows: "NBA Top Shot: USD $1,150.00 - USD $250,000.00 LeBron James - available from 356 sellers". So that is all you could extract. That is why REGEX was needed to extract just the low-end price.

Comment: This site also requires login for access. So if you don't have login credentials, it's only by luck that I could even extract as much as I was.